# Nativescript - XSS Prevention

Tags: xss, nativescript

Does a mobile application written with Nativescript, which utilizes a cross-platform Javascript runtime, have the same XSS vulnerability as a website?

Answer (score 8):

Well, in the strictest sense of the definition of XSS, no.     However security vulnerabilities in general -- I guess that depends on several factors about your application.  In the strictest sense a normal app the answer would be no; because in a normal application it is not written to download or run any external or user code.    So since you don't download or run any external code; that eliminates that risk.

So in a normal application; no.  However, if you make some app that actually allows a third-person to run there own JS inside your app; then yes by running any JS you open up the opportunity to compromise your app.  But that really wouldn't be XSS, it would just be a security vulnerability you created as you are allowing others to run code in your app.  (This is the same with ANY environment, the minute you allow someone to run code in your app; you open the doors for all sorts of mischief)

Now if this "extra" code is downloadable from a website; then you could get a XSS like issue where "BadGuy" posts a JS file on your website and then while extolling the virtues of how cool his script is, "NaiveGuy" downloads and runs it.  Bam, NaiveGuy has his phone compromised by a script that you have on your website...    But again this is something you would HAVE to specifically make this type of system to allow this to occur; this is not an issue built into NativeScript...

Two notes;

1. Any platform can suffer from this issue; NativeScript, React Native, Ionic, Cordova, WebSites, Node, Java, C, etc -- you allow a BadGuy to run code inside your app; you are in deep trouble security wise...
2. If you are using a WebView component in your NativeScript App (or any other language), then the WebView component itself can have XSS issues totally unrelated to NativeScript based on the website have it go to, as the WebView is a true Web browser component and it will do exactly what Chrome or Firefox would do on the site...  But any XSS issues in the WebView caused by the website doesn't correlate to an issue inside NativeScript as the WebView is isolated from NativeScript...

Comment: AFAIK, in languages other than Javascript, a user input cannot be executed as a piece of code but in Javascript we have eval(). And more importantly, in browsers, even though you don't use eval(), user input might be injected into the DOM as an executable piece of code unless escaped properly. I see that Nativescript uses a binding mechanism similar to that used in other client-side templating frameworks. Is it possible that an unescaped user input might change the context in an xml tag and insert a tap event handler for example?

Comment: @JohnL.actually many scripting languages have an eval type construct; and those that don't it isn't hard to embed one.   I've embedded tinyC into a C program so I can add 'C' scripting to a app.     But non-the-less; if you choose to run the end users "code" by using a eval like construct then this is your responsibility to sandbox it in a fashion to eliminate the risk that you just created.   None of the languages by default will auto-eval user input.   You get this issue when you display a html document with embedded user input and you improperly escaped that user input.

Comment: @JohnL.- NativeScript uses native components; so if you say display `<A onclick="blah()">` inside a field on the screen it will actually display that as is (i.e. pure text); no need to escape as the controls themselves are native controls and they don't do any parsing of html.    The only way for "blah()" to run would be for you to manually call "blah()"...    Now there are TWO controls that will parse html; WebView (because it is a full browser control) and HTMLView (because it is designed to parse a limited subset of html).   If you choose to pass unfiltered user input to them...

Comment: @JohnL.then they will run the code as they trust that you are passing to them what you want them to run.   However, the WebView is its own sandbox; so code running inside the WebView won't impact your NS code; unless you manually create some sort of bridge on the NS side to proxy commands from the WebView side.